# Conversion of varchar into datetime data type

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, varchar

This is in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio; I have a column `Order_Date` in my table, and the data type is `datetime`.

In my ASP.NET web application, I am inserting the date using this query:

```
"INSERT INTO Order (ORDER_DATE) VALUES ('" + System.DateTime.Now + "')";
```

I've done the same thing before in another project but didn't get error there. Here I'm getting error when try to insert data. How can I solve this error?

[image]

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be executing SQL commands in this manner. Either use parameterised stored procedures, or go overboard and use Entity Framework.

The reason is that hardcoding SQL is dificult to maintain and also leaves you open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will consider it.

Comment: @Urwah, see [this article](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) for more info on parameters and examples. A parameterized query will avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.DateTime.Now` will automatically be converted to a string by C# when it is appended to your `INSERT` string. However the string it produces will be dependent on the regional/culture settings on the box on which it is executing. It is exceptionally unlikely to produce a datetime string format that SQL understands. So you need to ensure that the correct format is used by explicitly setting it when the string is generated:

```
"INSERT INTO Order (ORDER_DATE) Values ('" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "')";
```

Comment: I have one more question  "Select * , Phone# as Phone  from tbl_OrderWHERE Order_Date IN ('" + from + "' , '" + to + "')" ............. from and to are strings taken from text boxes. in text i attached calender extender . How can i convert the date here?

Comment: Convert the strings to DateTime values first (or does the calendar control provide a property that gives you that value anyway?) and then call `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` on that. But I would **seriously** consider @CaptainKenpachi 's point re. not constructing inline queries in this way.

Comment: I would do it without the dashes (`yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss.fff`). Try with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;` first to see why.

Comment: If you *did* want to use the dashes, ensure there is a `T` between `dd` and `hh`, as then the value is no longer ambiguous. Of course, parametrisation doesn't have any of these flaws.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.Now I started working through parameters.

Answer (score -2):

You could just make it a SqlType like:

`"INSERT INTO Order (ORDER_DATE) Values ('" + new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString() + "');"`

Check out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime